# What does the (C) stand for

Tags: plc

I have an input labled on the wire I4:11  but it is going to position 14 on the card.  In the program under alias and (field next to alias cant think of name of it) I:4.data.11(C)  .. Not sure what the `(C)` stands for  and why this is working if the wire is actually going to position 14 on the card not 11?

By position 14, i say this cause the number above the screw for this slot says 14

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the context I'm guessing you have a Rockwell ControlLogix program converted from an older SLC or PLC5 program.

The (C) means the tag is aliased to a *Controller Scope* tag.

Comment: Controller scope , Thanks.  Also found the card has commons on it that they are counting as numbers..so apparently the numbers on the card are NOT the actual data location... i find that dum but owell..